# Laravel, запуск в продакшн с vite, npm run build не собирается и выдает ошибку и ругается на storage link

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, storage, vite

Первый раз загружаю на хостинг, помогите пожалуйста. Laravel+Vue не собирается, выдает ошибку после npmrun build, точнее ругается на storage link, видать хочет полный путь. Можно ли это обойти?

Ошибка:

**vite v4.0.4 building for production...
✓ 3 modules transformed.
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "storage/insta.png"**

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @aleksandr barakin хорошо

Comment: а вы делали php artisan storage:link?

Comment: @n.osennij, да делала. Сейчас до сервера достучалась, но теперь ошибка "iled to load module script: ", видит blade файлы, но не компоненты(

Comment: наверное, что-то не так с настройками сервера и npm. Не знаю. Соберите проект локально